# How to fix `Unexpected input report number 128` spam in logs?

Tags: mouse, logs

My logs are absolutely spammed with this message:

> logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C537.0002: Unexpected input report number 128

I do a Logitech G602 mouse that I use. Is this spam fixable?

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same mouse and the same error print. I found that the line prints reliably when I move the DPI switch, but can also print during clicks and mouse moves (but not as reliably). Running Arch with Zen kernel. I get the same print with and without Solaar

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies in the hid-logitech-dj driver which do not properly handle the G602 mouse and those generates this error message.
Sadly the original author of the driver Nestor Lopez Casado nlopezcasad@logitech.com has decided to not take up the task to fix this issue.
Some people have said that blacklisting the logitech drivers has removed the error, but not sure how well the mouse works after that.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
Besides the bulky log (which log file contains those messages?), do mouse buttons work fine?
If so, one can try to avoid such messages going into the log, like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/75896/is-there-any-way-to-exclude-specific-entries-from-linux-log-files).

---

As per [this](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg71897.html), you might need a kernel upgrade.
Please post the output of the following commands (I may extend the list depending on the output you post):

```
$ uname -a
```

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1962369#p1962369) and [this](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/issues/1124) also show that the Logitech G602 is having issues with very recent kernels.

Comment: no OP, but I'm having the exact same issue on the latest Arch kernel. `Linux KURTSARCHLAPTOP 5.12.9-zen1-1-zen #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT Thu, 03 Jun 2021 11:36:07 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @Kurtoid - I always suggest you write your own OP to place a bounty. That way you can make updates needed to move ahead towards a solution (and thus making it clearer for the readers, the best way to help others help you) without tainting the existing one.
Also, see EDIT.

Comment: @Kurtoid - Note that this is a forum for Ubuntu. It is not clear whether the distro might be behind possible differences in a solution for Ubuntu vs. your case.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is probably better suited for you in this case.

Comment: @Kurtoid - Do you have any comment on the EDIT?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio if making your own post requires you to post an already posted question, It will just be down voted and closed.  --regarding your 1st comment

Comment: @JonSkeet - I guess there is no absolute formula for this, in particular in askubuntu.
In SO, a specific question about Python (e.g.) often has a specific solution that is arrived at in "one shot".
In askubuntu, the solution to problems often relies on "iterations" more than in other SE sites, typically the same as in forums like https://www.linuxquestions.org/, https://ubuntuforums.org/, etc.
So posting a question that is similar to an existing one might soon "diverge" from the from the first with iterations.
My suggestion applies specifically to askubuntu.

Comment: Makes sense. Ill keep that in mind. Thanks for clarifying. Even in SO they take it too far imo. I am always seeing Qs closed for resembling 10 yr old Qs with same title/ symptoms and different underlying issue. In many cases the referenced posts are completely obsolete. Flaggers usually just look at the titles. In most cases that may work, but that doesn't help the users w/ the newer issue.

Comment: And unfortunately I know what you mean about the iterations. Many o' Saturdays & Sundays I've spent trying to fix a single issue in linux. At first, I'm primed & ready, doin the extra reading on related subjects, etc. By 2:30 the next morning, however, I'm just throwing hail Marys in hopes that they'll land & I can go to bed..  : )

Comment: First dedicated Linux box (WIP) since… 2010, and I get this crap.  Two entries per mouse button click.  Kernel is 5.15.5, just built today (I built my own kernel, also first time in ages :D… to get the NTFS3 driver, that Debian hasn't enabled in stock kernels yet)

_sigh_  Over twenty years of Linux (Debian throughout) and still this… (oh, and over 30 years with these beasts, because Windows isn't really that much better)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this continues to be an issue. Posted details into https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/issues/832#issuecomment-1073410529 (related)

Comment: IMO, this should probably be a comment to the question, not a new answer. I'll watch the github issue, though. Thank you!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1213448)

Comment: this is NOT an answer, just another reference (I don't understand how it got marked as an answer)